# Code that used to work now doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I had a problem a few weeks ago with some code [and it was solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097991/problems-checking-whether-a-table-exist-or-not-in-the-db) now my problem lies when I come back to this project and try to use the code that was working but now it doesn't work somehow.... even when i try it alone....
 the error that i get in Apache is

```
"[28-Aug-2012 16:24:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Proj11\2.php on line 49"
```

the line 49 is the if statement

I really dont know where is the problem as it used to work before... can anyone give me a hint on what could be my problem?? I has to be a server problem right? thanks

```
$results = $db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'pages\'');
if (count($results->fetchAll()) > 0) {
    echo 'table exists';
} else {
    echo "it doesnt";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$results` is set properly? Is `$db` working?

Comment: It always surprises me how people are asking for troubles. Assumption that `fopen()` or `query()` is always successful is plain naive. And you go the example. Also instead of writing `query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'pages\'');` you'd end with clearer code by doing `query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'pages'");`

Answer (score 1):

Your error means that `$results` is not getting an object. `$db->query` returns `null`

I also see a difference between the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097991/problems-checking-whether-a-table-exist-or-not-in-the-db) and your current code.

```
$db->query('SHOW TABLE LIKE \'page\'');
```

has now become

```
$db->query('SHOW TABLE LIKE \'pages\'');
```